# When the SAP domain is changed, will links/images break for all previous email sends?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sap

There's really not an easy way to test this in my account, but I'm hoping someone might have a quick answer to this.  When the "authenticated" SAP domain is changed from, say, abc.com to email.abc.com, will this break images and links for emails sent prior to updating the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all historical links will break as all of the links inside the email will continue to point to the old SAP domain.

Support might be able to help you place a redirect of all URLS to a specific page - but you are messing with a SAP which is core for a lot of functionality so it's unlikely to be an easy task to keep existing links alive.